# logical equivalence: (q ∧ p) ∨ ¬(q ∨ ¬q) = p and q

Tags: logic

I need to prove logical equivalence for : $(q\land p)\lor\neg (q\lor\neg q) = p\land q$

So far I have lhs:≡ $(q\land p)\lor\neg (q\lor\neg q)$

Step 1: $(q\land p)\lor (\neg q\lor\neg\neg q)=$ De Morgan's law

Step 2: $(q\land p)\lor (\neg q\lor q)=$ Double negation law

Having trouble with the next steps, I'm not sure what to put next.

Comment: You applied DeMorgan incorrectly. Also are you allowed to use the Law of Excluded Middle?

Comment: Ok what did I do wrong? Wait the or has to change to an and). No law of excluded middle sorry.

Answer (score 1):

As @player3236 said, you applied DeMorgan incorrectly. Please note that:
\begin{equation*}
\neg (q \vee \neg q) = \neg q \land q
\end{equation*}
And so you have:
\begin{equation*}
(q \land p)\vee \neg(q\vee \neg q) =(q \land p) \vee \underbrace{(\neg q \land q)}_{= False} = q \land p 
\end{equation*}